# vb.net Pick random function

Tags: arrays, vb.net, function

I want to choose a random function from a list of functions. I tried to start out like this:

```
Dim Functions As Array = {F1(), F2(), F3()}
```

But it causes an exception. How would I make it so I could pick a random function?

Comment: The problem with this is that in your creation of the Array of functions there are in fact being called - each of them so they all will run - probably not what you want.

Comment: Why not pick a random number between 1 and 3 then use `If/Select Case` to invoke one or the other depending on the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list of delegates.  For instance, you could use the provided `Action` delegate:

```
Dim r As New Random()
Dim functions() As Action  = {AddressOf F1, AddressOf F2, AddressOf F3}
' ...
functions(r.Next(functions.Length)).Invoke()
```